# OpenNMS: Event unassigned, listed under "assigned to anyone but you"

Tags: opennms

I'm new to OpenNMS and I've set it up to monitor some devices on the network but most importantly to receive SNMP traps from a few HP servers through iLO.

I'm done with what I thought was going to be the hardest part, getting the SNMP events to trigger notices. For that, I've created a REGEX event notification that matches all iLO events and assigned the path "Email-Admin".
This path includes my user (admin).
When I trigger an event, it appears but shows up under "1 of 1 assigned to anyone but you".

Like I mentioned above the path for the notification is "Email-Admin" and my user is part of the "Admin" group that is associated to that path.
I've checked things like the "On-Call Schedule" but if I visit that page while testing it shows my user as "On-Call", so I don't think that's the reason why I don't get assigned the event.

The ultimate goal is to get email/slack/sms notifications working but I can't get them to be assigned to my user in the first place.

On the notice list, the "Responder" column for the events is blank.

Anything I've missed?